# What expressions should I use to reply "sorry to be a pain, but …" courteously

Tags: phrases, politeness, business-language

Last week, my colleague asked me to help on something, he said, “Sorry to be a pain, I just hoping to get it done shortly”. Actually, it didn’t bother me at all and it is a part of my job. Is there a courteous English phrase should I use to reply this kind of questions?
Thank you for any advice in advance. :)

Comment: Hi Jacky, welcome to English Language & Usage (EL&U), which is "a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts". You may not be aware of another site, [ELL.se], which might be very useful for you; it provides a "library of detailed answers to every question about learning the English language." FWIW, a reply of "It's no trouble at all" or "I'm happy to help" is a standard courtesy.

Answer (score 2):

*All in a day's work. Don't mention it.*

Should convey what you want to say pretty courteously.

Answer (score 1):

"It's no trouble"

"Don't apologize!"

"Don't worry about it"

"That's fine, it's what I'm here for"

"No problem"

"Sounds great"

"I'll get right on it"

Answer (score -1):

If you're on close enough terms with your correspondent, I like the Aussie slang "no wuckers", which derives from the spoonerism "no wucking furries".

Comment: That is nice, but considering its origins, I don't think I would recommend it to someone who is asking for a "courteous" phrase to use with a colleague.

Comment: Well, not unless he or she has Aussie notions of courtesy.